# yolov5, I'm making a drowsiness detection

Tags: python, opencv, yolov5

It is executed, but it does not work as intended. Training was conducted with a custom dataset, and classes include [R_open, L_open, R_close, L_close]. When both R_close and L_close are recognized, a buzzer is sounded and the count is increased. How do I fix this?

There is a full code below.

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk 

import torch
import numpy as np

import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import winsound

app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry("600x600")
app.title("Drowsy Boi 4.0")
ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")

vidFrame = tk.Frame(height=480, width=600)
vidFrame.pack()
vid = ctk.CTkLabel(vidFrame, text='')
vid.pack()

counter = 0 
counterLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master = app, text=counter, height=40, width=120, font=("Arial", 20), text_color="white", fg_color="blue")
counterLabel.pack(pady=10)

def reset_counter(): 
    global counter
    counter = 0 
resetButton = ctk.CTkButton(master = app, text="Reset Counter", command=reset_counter, height=40, width=120, font=("Arial", 20), text_color="white", fg_color="teal") 
resetButton.pack()

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='D:/22.08.17code/monitor/best.pt', force_reload=True)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
def detect():
    global counter
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 
    results = model(frame)
    img = np.squeeze(results.render())

    if len(results.xywh) > 1:
        if results.xywh[0][0][5] == 'R_close' or results.xywh[0][0][5] == 'L_close' or results.xywh[1][0][5] == 'R_close' or results.xywh[1][0][5] == 'L_close':
            winsound.Beep(
            frequency=440,  # Hz
            duration=1000  # milliseconds
            )
            counter += 1 

    imgarr = Image.fromarray(img)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgarr) 
    vid.imgtk = imgtk
    vid.configure(image=imgtk)
    vid.after(10, detect) 
    counterLabel.configure(text=counter)  


detect()
app.mainloop()
```

I referred to that YouTube video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msGOrJIMGy8&t=935s

To sound a buzzer and increase the count

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you examined `results` and `results.xywh` to see if they are what you expect them to be?

Comment: I am new to yolov5. Results from the YouTube video mentioned.I tried using xywh and found out that it meant the coordinates of bounding box. However, I am not sure how to handle this bounding box.

What I want is to output a warning tone through a buzzer when it is a close class. Can I use a method other than results.xywh()?